# I am getting all broken images and alternative text of image in my reactjs project ,any solution for this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, broken-image

when i run the project the images in the project aren't visible in the browser,is there any solution for visible of images in the browser!
project is running smooth but the images aren't visible.
where my

[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R89Wv.png)

my mproject link

https://vscode.dev/github/darkleas/company-website-reactjs/blob/main
please show me an where was an retify it.!!!
please help me,i had tried different approaches but i had getting same.

1. [here the broken images for card.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTfWA.png)
   [header.js broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCT3w.png)
   [about.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhez9.png)

Answer (score 0):

The React bundler requires you to import static files using the `import` keyword (which returns a string) before using them, to ensure they refer to the same file in the build folder.

Create react app documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Eg:

```
import logo from './logo.png'

function Component(){
    return <>
        {//Other JSX}
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
    </>
}
```

Comment: it is still not working..

Answer (score 0):

As per your folder structure, It seems like you have stored images in the **public directory**. In order to access those images, you have to enter the path as `/img/img1.png` which refers to the path **relative** to the public folder.

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <div>
      //Public directory image
      <img src="/img/img1.png" />
    </div>
)
}
```

If you have images somewhere in the `src` folder, you can follow the approach mentioned by Shakya above.

```
import logo from './logo.png'

function App(){
    return <div>
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
    </div>
}
```